# Super Newb: Problems with XHR

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me. As mentioned in the title, I'm attempting to fight my way through an intro course and I'm struggling pretty hard with this particular issue.

**HERE IS WHAT I NEED TO DO:**

"Now we can start using APIs to get information from others applications. Lets create a Weather app [like this one](https://mariandreamv.github.io/weatherapp.github.io/).

this project consist on create an app that takes the name of any city via input and display the current weather and the weather for the next 7 days.

The main point of this project is learn how to get info from the API and handle multiple promises.

You will get the input value (city name) from the element with the 'id=city' in the index.html file.

Each time the user clicks the 'search' button the program has to get the city name from the input (validation is required) and make the API call. Write all the javascript code in 'weather.js' file.

You need to create an account in OpenWeather and then you will be able to get an API KEY
[how to start with OpenWeather API](https://openweathermap.org/appid)

OpenWeather has differents API calls. You can see all the options [here](https://openweathermap.org/api)

We are using two of those:

- [Current weather data](https://openweathermap.org/current)
- [One Call API](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api)

All right first things first. You are going to create a re-useful fetch function to get data form the API

The first API call (current weather data) is getting a response with the current weather for an specific city name (lets use the option **By city name**). The response also contains the latitude (lat) and longitude (lon) things that you will need for the next API call."

**HERE'S WHAT I'VE DONE:**

```
//Initialisation of variables
const myAPI = `hidden`;
let currentWeather = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Garner&appid=${myAPI}`;
let oneCallAPI = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&exclude={part}&appid=${myAPI}`;
let btn = document.getElementById('search');


function getWeather(url) { 
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open('GET', url); 
    xhr.onload = () => { 
      if(this.status === 200) { 
        let data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); 
        console.log(data); 
      } else{
          console.log('error');
      }
    }; 
    xhr.send(); 
  }

getWeather();

//   btn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
//     getWeather(currentWeather); 
// });
```

When the page loads, I receive an error "XHR failed loading: GET "http://vscodeliveserveraddy/undefined" as well as my error message logged to the console.

Is the problem with my code? Or with my live server?
*Side note, my api key with OpenWeather also stops working intermittently. Is that normal?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `getWeather();` so you are passing **no** arguments.

`function getWeather(url) {` assigns the first argument to `url`, but since you didn't pass any that becomes `undefined`.

Then you use that variable here `xhr.open('GET', url);` which expects a string so it gets converted to `"undefined"` which is a relative URL so is concatenated with the URL of the current page.